# View is a event in Bloc pattern?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am doing a app for View Exercises Rutines. My app display a ListStore on the initial state with the names with all Rutines. My problem is, Do I need to have any variables in the ViewRutines event? I paste my Events code and my Rutine object.

```
abstract class RutineEvent extends Equatable {
  const RutineEvent();
}

class ViewRutines extends RutineEvent {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class RealizeRutine extends RutineEvent {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

Rutine Object

```
class Rutine extends Equatable{

  final ObjectId id;
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final String date;
  final Image image;
  final List<dynamic> exercises;

  const Rutine({this.id, this.name, this.description, this.date, this.image, this.exercises});

  @override
  String toString() => 'Rutine { id: $id name: $name description: $description date: $date image: $image exercises: $exercises }';

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id,name,description,date,image,exercises];
}
```

And other doubt is i should create a event for each action on my app?